# Entity framework 4 Underlaying provider failed on Open

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am trying to connect to the database but I am getting this exception:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name 
is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

I've googled a lot, but I could not find the answer.

Here's my configuration:

I use MS SQL Server 2008 Express. Both Sql Server and Sql Server Browser use my account (I am an administrator). I've also used local system and local service. Without success.

Here is my connectionstring in app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EventManagerEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.RelationModel.csdl|res://*/Entities.RelationModel.ssdl|res://*/Entities.RelationModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=martijn-laptop\sql2008;Initial Catalog=EventManager;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

I've also tried to use the sql server username and password, also without success.

I am using winforms. What else can I try?

When I check netstat -an I get this:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:1433           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    [::]:1433              [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

I don't think this is correct, right? But how do I set it right?

Comment: Is your instance named Sql2008? Default name is SQLExpress.

Comment: Yes, I've changed that during installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot find instance/server. Telnet the 1433th or the configured port of martijn-laptop\sql2008 to verify its accessible

Comment: I just edited my post. I don't think the results are correct, but I don't how to correct this.

Comment: netstat and telnet are different as i know. And, are you surely making tests from the machine where the app is running?

Comment: When I type telnet, I get the message that `'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`. Everything is running on my laptop: sql server 2008 and VS

Comment: What is the operating system? If windows 7, turn on telnet client from features

Comment: Thnx. When i type `telnet martijn-laptop 1433` I get a black screen with a cursor and that's it. I don't get any (error) messages

Comment: @archil: Do you think you can help me further?

Comment: @Martijn as it seems by telnet, the server is really listening to the default port. Once more, let's make sure the instance name is correct. Try connecting to '.' instead of martijn-laptop\sql2008.

Comment: @archil. I am at work right now. I will try it later when I get home. I'll let you know what the result is. One more thing, I have  created a brand new project. In this project I create a SqlConnection with the same (copy/paste) connection string which I use in the EF project. When I run a query on the connection, it gives me results. I don't know much about EF, but maybe it is the EF condfiguration?

Comment: No, connection string is connection string, EF is not misusing it. One more thing that im thinking of is that maybe when creating your ef datacontext, you specified connection string manually in overloaded constructor. In this case, Ef would use that manual connection string and not the one written in web.config. If another project with same configuration works well, than it's more likely not the case with sql server installation

Comment: Okay, I know the connection string in app.config is working just fine (because of the test project). So I will check the connection string is specified manually in overloaded constructor. When I get home, I let you know what the results are :)

Comment: I use the default constructor of EF context. The base is called with these parameters values: `name=EventManagerEntities` as the connectionstring and `EventManagerEntities` as the containerName. My startpost contains the content of the app.config file. For completeness I get the exception at `myContext.myObjects.ToList();`

Comment: It works! I have no idea what the problem was, but now it just works! Thnx for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

Go into the SQL Server Configuration Manager and make sure you have the protocols you want to use enabled under "SQL Server Network Configuration" > "Protocols for Sql2008"

Comment: I have those enabled (TCP/IP, Named pipes and shared memory)

Answer (score 0):

From the error it seem like there is connectivity to database issue. Assuming this solution has been working elsewhere have you setup and connected to a different database?

Is so validate that the code generated with edmx has the correct default database connection name or that you are overriding it:

```
var context = new EventManagerContext("EventManagerEntities");
```

Or whatever the correct systax for EF is.

Comment: This line works fine. I get the error at `_context.Branches.ToList();`

Comment: I try to create the database based on the code. So I'll go for code first.